# Pull database file from deployed work tree of bare repo

Tags: git

I use git to deploy a website to a server.

The git repository is bare. I use a post-receive hook to get the files into the work tree (deployed website), with this kind of structure:

```
/var/git/repo.git <-- bare
/var/www/deployed_website <-- work tree of post-receive hook
```

In the deployed website directory on the server, there is a sqlite database that gets updated daily.

I would like to pull the database to my local machine so I can work with the most recent version of the database locally.

I cannot pull because, as I understand it, you can't pull from a bare repo.

What options do I have for reconfiguring this setup so that I can pull the database from the server to my local machine?

Comment: If you are not using version control on your website, why are you trying to pull from Git in the first place?

Comment: I use the version control aspect of git on my local machine to develop & test the site. When I'm satisfied with the changes, I push them to the server using git. Am I not using version control in this situation?

Comment: You can pull from a bare repo. If the database is tracked and updated in Git, you can always pull and get it. If the database is not tracked by Git, you need something else to do the job, `scp` for example.

Comment: Every time I try git status in the barerepo, it says: `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`. If I cd into the work tree, I get `fatal: Not a git repository`. I tried adding work tree to git config in the bare repo but now I get `fatal: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense`. I've read for several hours about git but still do not understand what I need to do to track and commit changes on the server.